# android tcp ip based screen copy forward to udp address

Tags: tcp, stream, udp, video-streaming

Currently, I'm using  [android screen copy](https://github.com/Genymobile/scrcpy) to get phone image down on mobile raspberry pi for sending over the local ethernet.  The goal is to process the phone image from a local server PC with a powerful GPU.

My pipeline is : Android -> (wireless) Raspberry PI (ethernet) -> ground host server PC(in far away server room)

The result  on the  Raspberry PI is sth like this

[image]

Im using the following command on the   Raspberry PI  to connect to the android.

```
adb tcpip 5555 
adb connect 192.168.1.19:5555
scrcpy
```

I need to forward the data to server-based image processing to process the data in real-time.

Question

(1) how do I get the video in scrcpy tcpip then port forward to an UDP address such as  udp://192.168.5.10:23003. I tried to change tcpip to udp. it doesnt work. The idea is minimize the processing on the RPI.

Noted I can not encode using  Raspberry PI  ffmepg because of the slow processing lag. Only forward the data steam is possible

(2) How to do thing such as "I just a click of app"  to auto start the whole streaming process

I deal with computer vision algorithm a lot, this android + network configuration is a bit confusing, hope I made myself clear on the intention.